# Urls treated like normal text - TinyButStrong

Tags: php, url, textarea, tinybutstrong

I have been trying to solve this for a while now, but it sounds like there is no hope :(

So I have a Textarea that takes text input form the user, then the message gets pushed into the chat using TinyButStrong. The problem is, if the user enters any type of url in the Textarea and submits, it will be published to the chat as a normal text.

```
<div class="messaging-text line-height-normal"> 
   <!--[messages.messages_text;comm;htmlconv=no]--> 
</div>
```

I think its something to do with TinyButStrong but I might be wrong, any ideas on why this could be happening? It's driving me crazy!

Comment: For awhile I thought it might be a problem with the CKEditor that I'm using with the Textarea, but I don't think so since I tested it even without the CKEditor and still hitting the same issue.

Comment: TinyButStrong does not auto convert url text to html <a>.  Would this be the problem?  If not, can you add a bit more code to make [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?